# Magento2 Xml Download

Tags: magento2

`simplexml_load_file($xmlFile)` 
this

> function working fine on **local server** but now loading xml on a **live server**

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: It just loading . no erroe founds

Comment: I've posted an answer but it _may_ not solve it as we don't have an error to go on, it's possible you also have an error level set that doesn't allow errors to be printed on the screen

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that your php.ini on the server is set to `allow_url_fopen` to off.

You should check and confirm this is set to on to allow `simplexml_load_file()` to work

If you do

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

It will show you your php.ini location which you can then edit.

[image]